# Using function pointers is slower than switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, function-pointers

I have this piece of code for testing the behaviour of switch statement versus function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int mySum(int startingValue)
{
    return startingValue += 1;
}

int mySub(int startingValue)
{
    return startingValue -= 1;
}


int main()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("USING SWITCH\n");
    printf("Start time: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

    int startingValue = 25;
    int currentOperation = 0;

    // Using switch
    for (long long i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++)
    {
        switch (currentOperation)
        {
            case 1:
                startingValue = mySum(startingValue);
                break;
            case 0:
                startingValue = mySub(startingValue);
                break;
        }

        if (currentOperation)
            currentOperation = 0;
        else
            currentOperation = 1;
    }

    printf("Result is: %d\n", startingValue);

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("End time: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

    printf("\n\n\n");

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("USING FUNCTION POINTERS\n");
    printf("Start time: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

    startingValue = 25;
    currentOperation = 0;

    // Using function pointers
    int (*mySwitchOfFunctionPointers[2])(int x);
    mySwitchOfFunctionPointers[0] = &mySub;
    mySwitchOfFunctionPointers[1] = &mySum;
    for (long long i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++)
    {
        startingValue = (*mySwitchOfFunctionPointers[currentOperation])(startingValue);

        if (currentOperation)
            currentOperation = 0;
        else
            currentOperation = 1;
    }

    printf("Result is: %d\n", startingValue);

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("End time: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is this so code executes instantly with switch statement but it needs many seconds with function pointers:

```
USING SWITCH
Start time: Mon Oct 25 18:04:06 2021
Result is: 25
End time: Mon Oct 25 18:04:06 2021



USING FUNCTION POINTERS
Start time: Mon Oct 25 18:04:06 2021
Result is: 25
End time: Mon Oct 25 18:04:34 2021
```

Compiled with

```
gcc -c main.c -o test.o -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused -std=c99
gcc test.o -o test
```

Why the second approach is slower than the first??? Is there something wrong in the code? Any idea?

Comment: The function calls in the switch statement are probably inlined

Comment: Maybe the compiler replaces the loop in the `switch` version with nothing, but can't do the same with the `function pointer` version

Comment: try putting it into [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: @pmg ??? So gcc has a big bug?

Comment: The first loop is being optimized out completely.

Comment: @Francesco It's not a bug if it gets the correct answer.

Comment: It's calculating the result at compile time.

Comment: Try `int startingValue = 25;` --> `volatile int startingValue = 25;`

Comment: Definitely some extreme optimizations happening with `-O3` for the `switch` statement. If you use `-O0`, [godbolt times out](https://godbolt.org/z/T8hv8W8x9). The function pointer method times out with either flag.

Comment: On my machine with -O0 switch needs 54 seconds and function pointers 52 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can inline the switch and then the optimizer is smart enough to realize that your entire loop is a no-op so optimizes it out.
It does not do this with the function pointers.
See https://godbolt.org/z/qxxoof5cn

If you change your code to something that the compiler cannot optimize out so trivially you will get very different results. For example:

```c
int mySum(int startingValue)
{
    return startingValue += rand();
}

int mySub(int startingValue)
{
    return startingValue -= rand();
}
```

Comment: So in terms of emulation if I replace the big switch for CPU opcode in my CPU interpreter  with an array of function pointers can I get some improvement in terms of execution speed?

Comment: I don't think you can draw that conclusion without profiling both cases. There are a lot of variables that will affect your results... (e.g. compiler optimization, CPU cache behavior, branch prediction, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler optimization argument  (-O3) is responsible for this behaviour.

The compiler can optimize the first `for`-Loop  with the `switch` inside, because it has every needed information about this code.

Unfortunately the compiler can't optimize code with function-pointers. Since the compiler do not know what functions are called.

If you delete the -O3 argument at compiling, you will see that, function pointers and the `switch-case` statements need similar times.

Comment: I agree with you, I wrote the same thing in a previous comment. So it is a myth that using function pointers is faster than switch statement. With -O0 the time is very similar. With -O3 and rand() function inside mySum and mySub (instead of += 1 and -= 1) the difference is only 2%